# Reference for a result in group theory

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, combinatorial-group-theory

There is a question on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/103985/groups-with-finitely-generated-center) regarding the finitely generated center of a finitely generated group.

In the first remark of the question it is written that "If $G$ is a finitely generated group with infinitely generated center $Z(G)$, then the quotient $G/Z(G)$ is not finitely presented (as follows from a result of B.H Neumann)."

I need the reference of this result; i.e., I want to know from which result of B.H. Neumann the first remark follows. It would be helpful for me. Thank you.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: It's not hard to prove. If $G/N$ was finitely presented, then the images in $N$ of a set of defining relators of $G/N$ would generate $N$, and so $N$ would be finitely generated.

Comment: @DerekHolt What images? How do you pass from a free epimorphism $F_1\to G/N$ to a free epimorphism $F_2\to N$? I don't see this to be honest.

Comment: @ Shaun: Thank you for useful links. Next time, I will keep these things in mind.

Comment: @DerekHolt: I did not get it. If $G/N$ is finitely presented group, then it will have finite number of relations. But how this implies that $N$ is finitely generated?

Comment: @DerekHolt There is a subtlety here, which is possibly what the Neumann result is plugging: there is no guarantee that the "given" presentation for $G/N$ is finite. It is, however, well known that if $H$ is finitely presentable then any infinite presentation admits a finite sub-presentation. Possibly Neumann proved this? (Does this subtlety make sense? Certainly I can see no issue with your proof once this is wound in.)

Comment: @ManpreetSingh You have to use that $N$ is central.

Comment: @user1729 Yes I was assuming the result that, if a group is finitely presentable, then it has a finite presentation on any generating set. I will write a brief answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a sketch proof. Let $X$ be a finite generating set of $G$, so $G = F_X/K$ for some $K$, where $F_X$ is the free group on $X$. Then $N = L/K$ for some $L$.

Now if $G/N \cong F_X/L$ has a finite presentation then it has one on the images of $X$ in $G/N$. Let $\langle X \mid R \rangle$ be such a presentation. Then, by definition, $L$ is the normal closure $\langle R^F \rangle$ of $R$ in $F$.

Now $L/K \le Z(F_X/K)$ implies that $N=L/K$ is generated by the finite set $\{rK : r \in R \}$.